# UIImagePickerController to another ViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

How to show image from UIImagePickerController to another ViewController.xib?

I have "ViewController1", and here I got this code:

```
- (IBAction)goCamera:(id)sender {


    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    UIImageView *theimageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    theimageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

}
```

How can I go to "ViewController2" and to show taken photo there? I use ViewController1 to take a photo and I want to show this taken photo in ViewController2 where I got a UIImageView. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is save the image within the app's folders as soon as you've received the image.

*This is important*,  because it helps with **memory management**.

You can let go of the image data, instead of passing it around the app.

I use code similar to the following:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *originalImage, *editedImage, *imageToSave;
    editedImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                               UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    originalImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                                 UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    imageToSave = (editedImage!=nil ? editedImage : originalImage);


    // Check if the image was captured from the camera
    if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
        // Save the image to the camera roll
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToSave, nil, nil, nil);
    }

    NSString *docspath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *filepathJPG = [docspath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"imagefile.jpg"];

    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToSave, 0.8);
    BOOL result = [data writeToFile:filepathJPG atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"Saved to %@? %@", filepathJPG, (result? @"YES": @"NO") );

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Then in your other view controller, wherever you would expect to load the image (viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear or wherever) put:

```
NSString *docspath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *filepathJPG = [docspath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"imagefile.jpg"];

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: filepathJPG];
if (img != nil) {
    // assign the image to the imageview, 
    myImageView.image = img;

    // Optionally adjust the size
    BOOL adjustToSmallSize = YES;
    CGRect smallSize = (CGRect){0,0,100,100};
    if (adjustToSmallSize) {
        myImageView.bounds = smallSize;
    }

}
else {
    NSLog(@"Image hasn't been created");
}
```

Hope that helps